# Web App Layout Guidelines

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I am transitioning from Desktop apps (WPF/Winforms) to Browser Apps and am looking for a good resource on laying out an app.  I don't mean design here, just the mechanics of the layout.

For example, "don't use tables for layout" seems to come up a lot.  I have come up with the below  as a really simple app layout that does not use tables (except for the actual data grid):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .layoutRoot {width: 960px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 25px;}
     div { border: 1px solid black;}
    span { border: 1px solid black;margin: 5px;}
    button { margin: 5px;}
    .floatLeft{ float: left; }
    .floatRight{ float: right;}
    .dataGrid {width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 1px solid blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="layoutRoot">
        <span class="floatLeft">My Site Name</span>
        <span class="floatRight" >Login Link</span>
        <table class="dataGrid"><tr><td>The Order Line Items goes here</td></tr></table>
        <button>Cancel Order</button>
        <button class="floatRight" >Continue</button>
        <span class="floatRight" >Order Total</span>
        <span class="floatRight" >Order Subtotal</span>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I have Googled the subject, but mostly finding design ("this looks good") as opposed to "this is how you do it."

Greg

Comment: Other than the massive amount of inline styles (which I personally try to stay away from), this is pretty good. Floating layouts are the way to go (as opposed to tables).

Comment: Good point, I updated the sample to use classes.

Comment: Yay! It's so much cleaner! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only suggestion for improvements would be to change the widths to percentages. When working with web apps and all of the resizing of windows and device sizes, it's better to make it responsive where you can. It just makes for better overall UX.

Comment: The only width I have set is the 960px.  How else would I set this?  If I don't set a width, on a 1600 px wide screen, it's just too wide.  (Although I suppose I could set max-width: 960px;)

Comment: Now you're thinking! Try something like: max-width: 960px; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; This will make it have a little margin and stretch with the page, but once it hits that max-width, it will just stay in the center at the fixed width.

Comment: No problem Greg! Good luck moving into web apps! It's fun! =)

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.

Just wanted to add that sometimes it can be useful to use a horizontal list for the layout as well. Sometimes it can get quite messy with floats when they get nested etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a horizontal list, but I do now!